# Should an EventEmitter be closed manually when the component is destroyed?

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I have a component with an `@Output` variable. This variable must be of type `EventEmitter` [according to the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

The `EventEmitter` looks allot like the `Observable` class. They share common methods, like `subscribe()`. One should unsubscribe to `Observables` after use in order to prevent memory leaks from occuring. Should one do the same with `EventEmitter` objects? Should i call `complete` on the object when the component is destroyed?

Comment: The question was flagged as opinion-based but, let me say, if this is opinion based then all the programming world is opinion based. By the way, `Output` EventEmitters share the same life cycle of the component. So you shouldn't care about them. You can call `complete` in other EventEmitters if your internal protocol requires it

Comment: @CristianTraìna that should be an Answer :)